# Etiquette when continuing work on a research direction without involving former collaborators

Tags: collaboration, interpersonal-issues

I have collaborated on a certain topic with researchers A, B and C, where A is my PhD supervisor (I'm now a post-doc), and B and C are senior colleagues from different universities. The collaboration lead to a number of papers, in which I was the main author, while A, B and C made important contributions.

I'm now working on an idea that continues the research direction of this earlier work. Since I already got pretty far with the execution of my idea, I don't expect much additional benefit from involving A-C at this stage. In fact, I would prefer to publish this work without them, since I'm in a career stage where the common advice is to assert myself as an independent researcher.

However, I have the feeling that A-C might be disappointed if I don't involve them - I certainly would, if I was in their position. Is there an etiquette for tactfully dealing with this kind of situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a feeling that you will disappoint them then, by all means, let them know! And indeed, you *should* let them know that you've continued this line of research independently.

You can phrase your invitation in a way that it hints that you would like to go on alone. Something like

> Lately, I was working *independently* on extensions regarding our previous work and I went pretty far and I have such-and-such results. I believe that these results are interesting enough to make a publication. I would like your opinion about this and about potential venues that would accept this paper.

By this, you make clear that this is *your* work, you acknowledge their expertise and definitely you give them a heads up. This is actually quite common and I expect them to either ignore it (if they are busy) or be happy that you were able to generalize it and give you valuable hints/advice.